# Kendo Angular Grid CSS - overwrite default link style

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to overwrite the default CSS in an Angular Kendo grid to display hyperlinks in a specific way.  Pretty basic, I want hyperlinks to display as blue and then hover with an underline, but I don't want this style applied to the headers.  I'm trying to use the 'not' selector, but it's still displaying in the headers.

```
.k-grid a:not(.k-grid-header) {
    color: $royal-blue !important;
}

.k-grid a:hover:not(.k-grid-header) {
    color: $dark-blue !important;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are these headers that *are* links or links in headers. Because it makes a difference in the selector.

Comment: The headers are links, basically they fire the sorting on the rows.  The Kendo CSS is kind of confusing.

Comment: The certainly the first rule should work (assuming you have `a.k-grid-header`, but the second, the hover should come at the end `a:not(.k-grid-header):hover`

Comment: Your best option is to inspect the element with developer tools (F12) and see what rules ARE applying `.k-link`? and see if there is a specificity / cascade issue. Hence the need for a demo... :)

Comment: Right, doing the inspecting.  And I get the need for a demo, just a lot of code and trying to figure out how to pare it down.

Comment: Nice Paulie_D, it was .k-link.  Added that to the not selector and it worked, thank you!